# How do I delete all files that match the basename in an array of globs?

Tags: javascript, gulp, glob

I have an existing `build` task in my `gulpfile`, that transforms a collection of "source" files into "dist" files. I have an array of well-known filenames that tell my `build` task which files to operate on:

```
sourceFiles: [
    "./js/source/hoobly.js",
    "./js/source/hoo.js"
    ]
```

My `build` task produces the following files from this:

- `./js/dist/hoobly.js`
- `./js/dist/hoobly.min.js`
- `./js/dist/hoobly.js.map`
- `./js/dist/hoobly.min.js.map`
- `./js/dist/hoo.js`
- `./js/dist/hoo.min.js`
- `./js/dist/hoo.js.map`
- `./js/dist/hoo.min.js.map`

I now want to write a corresponding `clean` task that removes the files that get generated during my `build` task. Unfortunately I cannot just delete **all** the files in the `./js/dist/` directory, as this contains other files that are not generated by the `build` task in question, so I need to ensure that the files I delete match the "basename" of the orginal `sourceFiles`.

My question is: how do I go about using the `sourceFiles` array and "munging"* it so that I can end up calling something like:

```
gulp.src(sourceFiles)
    .pipe(munge()) // I don't know what to do here!!
    .pipe(del());  // does a `del ./js/dist/hoobly.*`
                   // and a  `del ./js/dist/hoo.*`
```

(*Technical term, ["munge"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/munge)...)

Can you point me in the right direction? I've looked at various NPM packages (vinyl-paths, gulp-map-files, gulp-glob, ...) and I'm just getting more and more lost.

Comment: What is the question? Pass to del the files to be deleted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd change globs before passing them to `gulp.src`:

```js
var sourceFiles = [
    "./js/source/hoobly.js",
    "./js/source/hoo.js"
    ];
    
var filesToDelete = sourceFiles.map(f=>f.replace("/source/", "/dist/").replace(".js", ".*"));

console.log(filesToDelete)
```

and omit that `munge` step:

```
gulp.src(filesToDelete).pipe(del())
```